# ContentControl Value (Target Address)

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am currently working with content control in Microsoft Word 2016. In excel there is the "Intersect(Target, Range(xx,xx)" function, so the macro only activates based on a certain cells.

```
 Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

ContentControls(10).Range.Text = ContentControls(8).Range.Text
ContentControls(13).Range.Text = ContentControls(11).Range.Text
ContentControls(16).Range.Text = ContentControls(14).Range.Text

End Sub
```

Basically I only want the ContentControl to activate if the person exits from contentcontrols 8,11,14.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  i = .Range(0, CCtrl.Range.End).ContentControls.Count
  Select Case i
    Case 8, 11, 14: .ContentControls(i + 2).Range.Text = CCtrl.Range.Text
  End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't work as intended and compiler issue at End Select. What I need is location if I select a specific Content Controls.

Comment: Oops - somehow a spurious End Select crept in there. Corrected.